# SSIS 2005 How to add a zip task?

Tags: ssis

I have a ssis 2005 project.

I have to add a zipping task.ie, i have to zip a text file.

But i have to follow DB standards of the ORG. strictly.

1) No 3rd party software in the DB server.Not even resourec kit tools

2) No exe's in the DB server.

so i cant use(windows resource kit tools,7-zip, and a execute process task to invoke a c# exe.)

please suggest me a way to achieve zipping in ssis without compromising the DB standards.Any zip task is available as an addin to SSIS 2005?

Thanks

SNA

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Script Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141752(SQL.90).aspx), and write code using the [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class to compress the file.